# LegacyExchangeDN info showing up in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, imap

I've got a very odd Outlook problem. Windows 10 Pro, Outlook 2019, everything's up to date.

Here's the situation: the Outlook profile was set up using an exchange account as the primary address. Along with a few other exchange accounts, there are also a couple of IMAP accounts, one that's a basic IMAP server and two that are GSuite accounts that are accessed via IMAP. The primary account had been on a private exchange server and we recently migrated the domain to Office 365 Exchange. Because of the IMAP account, we did NOT change Outlook profiles, since that account credentials cannot be retrieved. We did a pst migration and everything's working fine within the exchange account itself.

We ran into a strange problem with calendar items, however. There were some recurring calendar items that when we tried to update that item, we received a bounceback saying we weren't authorized to send. Upon investigating, we noticed that when hovering over the From address in the calendar item, it showed what looked like a bunch of junk data. We reselected the account's address in the From dropdown and resent and everything worked fine to send.

Following this, we sent a calendar item from the exchange account to one of the GSuite accounts. The invite sent but showed up as Unknown User in Gmail and when looking at the full message, the sender's identity was the LegacyExchangeDN! Researching a bit more I tried rebuilding the Offline Address Books on the computer. This worked to fix the displayed address when checking in GMail (the correct email address shows up now) and we sent calendar items to a handful of other addresses using different services and that all shows up correctly on the recipient end.

The last bit of trouble is when viewing that calendar invitation in the GSuite account within Outlook. When looking in Outlook, the sender address shows as teh LegacyExchangeDN user info, not the exchange email address. We tried sending to another Exchange account on the same computer and the displayed address comes through correctly, it's only doing this for the accounts that are connected via IMAP.

We tried inserting the LegacyExchangeDN user as an email address in the contacts, but it just overwrites it with the email address, and I don't have the original LegacyExchangeDN from the old server, since that's not one that I manage.

Other than creating a new Outlook profile is there any way to either extract the LegacyExchangeDN user info from the original server that's stuck in Outlook, or just overwrite it so that the current user is correctly paired with this address?

Comment: Can this issue be reproduced on the web mail?

Comment: No, this ONLY happens when sending a calendar item from Outlook.

Comment: Regarding LegacyExchangeDN entry, I think you can check this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5c1492fd-b2ec-4a52-b05c-d7bd27f7eb0e/outlook-randomly-resolves-to-x500-address-instead-of-smtp?forum=outlook

Comment: Another problem is that you are not authorized to send meeting update, right?  I haven't found related articles but we may first try recreate the .ost file to test the results.

Comment: @Perry, there's no issue sending the meeting, no permissions problem on the exchange account. This is only showing the LEDN address when viewing the sender of a calendar invitation in the IMAP account that was sent from the Exchange account.

Comment: We tried clearing the OAB and setting the LEDN as an X.500 address in the contact list, neither worked.

Comment: According to the link above, we may also need to empty auto-complete list